# Only get data when value matches 100% of multiple other values SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables that I join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM color_photo c
LEFT JOIN photos p
ON c.photo_id = p.id
WHERE c.color_id IN (4,9,11)
```

Above gives the following result:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [photo_id] => 4
    [color_id] => 4
    [path] => photos/419d7f6ce1043f472faf44ee517c3c67.jpg
    [preview] => images/photos/previews/preview-9eba598915ea34de6d80b537a25610f3.jpg
    [thumbnail] => images/photos/thumbnails/thumb-9eba598915ea34de6d80b537a25610f3.png
    [name] => golden retriever mix dog walking in the forest.jpg
    [extension] => jpg
    [photographer_id] => 1
    [popularity] => 0
    [order] => 500
    [created_at] => 2021-07-16 11:32:55
    [updated_at] => 2021-07-16 11:32:55
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [photo_id] => 2
    [color_id] => 9
    [path] => photos/604af943f1565e02de8f3d98202f6226.jpg
    [preview] => images/photos/previews/preview-5fbba3dc932f4304712dfc65860679d1.jpg
    [thumbnail] => images/photos/thumbnails/thumb-5fbba3dc932f4304712dfc65860679d1.png
    [name] => 97903847_m.jpg
    [extension] => jpg
    [photographer_id] => 1
    [popularity] => 8
    [order] => 500
    [created_at] => 2021-06-23 10:08:49
    [updated_at] => 2021-07-16 15:01:01
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [photo_id] => 3
    [color_id] => 9
    [path] => photos/9bc2dc45f3473252d4353446c8dbc168.jpg
    [preview] => images/photos/previews/preview-9bc2dc45f3473252d4353446c8dbc168.jpg
    [thumbnail] => images/photos/thumbnails/thumb-9bc2dc45f3473252d4353446c8dbc168.png
    [name] => 94507149_m.jpg
    [extension] => jpg
    [photographer_id] => 1
    [popularity] => 7
    [order] => 499
    [created_at] => 2021-06-23 10:09:46
    [updated_at] => 2021-07-20 10:09:42
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [photo_id] => 1
    [color_id] => 11
    [path] => photos/c3b2e455ded9f954fed6a4e039dc6cfa.png
    [preview] => images/photos/previews/preview-c3b2e455ded9f954fed6a4e039dc6cfa.jpg
    [thumbnail] => images/photos/thumbnails/thumb-c3b2e455ded9f954fed6a4e039dc6cfa.png
    [name] => a2logo_opacity_big.png
    [extension] => png
    [photographer_id] => 1
    [popularity] => 7
    [order] => 500
    [created_at] => 2021-06-23 10:08:21
    [updated_at] => 2021-07-04 18:33:14
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [photo_id] => 3
    [color_id] => 11
    [path] => photos/9bc2dc45f3473252d4353446c8dbc168.jpg
    [preview] => images/photos/previews/preview-9bc2dc45f3473252d4353446c8dbc168.jpg
    [thumbnail] => images/photos/thumbnails/thumb-9bc2dc45f3473252d4353446c8dbc168.png
    [name] => 94507149_m.jpg
    [extension] => jpg
    [photographer_id] => 1
    [popularity] => 7
    [order] => 499
    [created_at] => 2021-06-23 10:09:46
    [updated_at] => 2021-07-20 10:09:42
)
```

The important rows for my question are `photo_id` and `color_id`. A photo can have multiple colors. As you can see `photo_id: 3` is present 2 times both with a different `color_id`. These color_ids are posted to this query from another page, so the `(4,9,11)` are dynamic and can be any combination.

I want to be able to filter photos by color. So for example a photo of a dog has three colors, `4,9,11`, the dog with `photo_id` 2 should show up. But when posting a color id that the dog photo does not have, for example 12, so you get `4,9,11,12` I want the dog to be removed from the result.

I know `IN` is not the correct SQL for this because it will just retrieve data that matches any of those color_ids. I want to retrieve only the photos that match all color_ids, and if there is one that doesn't match, remove this photo_id from the result entirely. How can I do this? I'm using MYSQL.

I've tried it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM color_photo c
LEFT JOIN photos p
ON c.photo_id = p.id
WHERE c.color_id = 4 AND c.color_id = 9
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM color_photo c
LEFT JOIN photos p
ON c.photo_id = p.id
WHERE c.color_id IN (4) AND c.color_id IN (9)
```

But both return no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple method for an exact match uses aggregation and filtering using `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM color_photo c LEFT JOIN
     photos p
     ON c.photo_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(c.color_id ORDER BY c.color_id) = '1,4,9';
```

If you wanted a subset match (so, there could be more colors in the photo), I would instead recommend:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM color_photo c LEFT JOIN
     photos p
     ON c.photo_id = p.id
WHERE c.color_id IN (1, 4, 9)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to exclude a photo with `4, 9` and `4, 9, 11, 999` when searching for `4, 9, 11` you could use the following:

```sql
SELECT p.id
FROM photos p
INNER JOIN color_photo c ON p.id = c.photo_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
AND COUNT(CASE WHEN c.color_id IN (4, 9, 11) THEN 1 END) = 3
```